# Maximize the Profit as the Salesman

Tags: dynamic-programming

https://leetcode.com/problems/maximize-the-profit-as-the-salesman/description/

Leetcode 2830. Maximize the Profit as the Salesman

You are given an integer n representing the number of houses on a number line, numbered from 0 to n - 1.

Additionally, you are given a 2D integer array offers where offers[i] = [starti, endi, goldi], indicating that ith buyer wants to buy all the houses from starti to endi for goldi amount of gold.

As a salesman, your goal is to maximize your earnings by strategically selecting and selling houses to buyers.

Return the maximum amount of gold you can earn.

Note that different buyers can't buy the same house, and some houses may remain unsold.

from typing import List

class Solution:
def search(self, sorted_offers, index):
for i in range(index + 1, len(sorted_offers)):
if sorted_offers[i][0] > sorted_offers[index][0]:
return i
return -1

```
def solve(self, sorted_offers, index, memo):
    if index >= len(sorted_offers):
        return 0
        
    if index in memo:
        return memo[index]
        
    ans = self.search(sorted_offers, index)
    if ans == -1:
        return 0

    #inc
    ans1 = sorted_offers[index][2] + self.solve(sorted_offers, ans, memo)
    #exc
    ans2 = self.solve(sorted_offers, index + 1, memo)
    memo[index] = max(ans1, ans2)
    return memo[index]
    
def maximizeTheProfit(self, n: int, offers: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    sorted_offers = sorted(offers, key=lambda x: x[0])
    return self.solve(sorted_offers, 0, {})
```

I tried this.. using dp and linear search but the first test case n = 5 offers = [[0,0,1],[0,2,2],[1,3,2]]
Output
2
Expected
3
is failing